# Best format for model with double UV sets

Tags: blender, assimp

I'd like to use first UV set as wrapping (or when some faces cover another on UV) diffuse color map and second UV set as baked ambient occlusion (packed to `islands`) map. It is possibly to use FBX or Collada .dae or other (what?) in this case? I read scene by Assimp library.

Answer (score 2):

Both FBX and Collada support multiple UV sets, as does Assimp as noted here: http://www.assimp.org/main_features.html

> Loads multiple UV and vertex color channels (current limit is 8)

However, methods for exporting those file-types from 3D modelling software vary from each program to the next and is beyond the scope of this SE site.

Comment: I've just exported my model to .dae. In blender I've changed renderer to Blender Renderer (previous I was using Cycles) and set up two textures to one material. I've set one texture to first UV and other texture to second UV. When I'm searching value '.png` or name of one of textures, there is not any result.